# Redirecting an old SSL domain to a new one on Heroku (w/ Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, heroku, dns

I've been googling for the past hour on this but can't quite get it nailed down.  Perhaps you guys can assist here!

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Old site is:

old.tld

New site is:

new.tld

A bunch of folks access one particular legacy url on the old site via SSL, i.e.:

https://www.old.tld/old_url

I've just setup a brand new site on Heroku, running Rails 3, on the new domain.

I also have installed Heroku's SSL Endpoint Add-on and am using a new secure subdomain:

secure.new.tld

I've got a bunch of redirects & constraints in my Rails routes.rb to redirect old -> new and pass the appropriate requests.  Everything works perfectly for the non-SSL stuff.

The only thing I can't seem to get working properly is the redirects of

https://www.old.tld/old_url -> https://secure.new.tld/new_url

Safari doesn't seem to mind, but Chrome is throwing a "This is probably not the site you are looking for!" error.  It says (only when trying via SSL):

"You attempted to reach www.old.tld, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as secure.new.tld"  Etc.

(which is exactly what I want, but Chrome doesn't seem to approve ;)

Any thoughts on how to properly configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seamless solution it is to get a SAN (Subject Alternative Name) certificate that has both the old name and the new name.

Another way is to insert a non-secure request in between the two secure requests: redirect from https://www.old.tld -> http://secure.new.tld -> https://secure.new.tld. I haven't actually tested this, but it should work in theory. If it doesn't "just work", then you might try adding an actual page at http://secure.new.tld with a message and a link to https://secure.new.tld.

Comment: Great suggestions - thanks.  I'll try the less-expensive option first (redirects) and, if no go, will go the SAN route.  I have a GeoTrust EV cert so it's $169/year for the additional domain - not terrible but still ;)

Comment: Ok - alas the redirect didn't work (Chrome seems a bit too smart - it saw that even thought there was a non-secure midpoint, the endpoint was a different site so the flag was getting thrown).  So I had to suck it up and purchase the UC/SAN certificate, which solved the problem perfectly.  Thank you for pointing out that this was necessary!  Didn't even know it was a thing :)