# Redirect Issues on two seperate domains for the same site

Tags: ssl, redirect, phoenix-framework, http-status-code-301

I have two domains: the original `my-site.co.uk` and a new `mysite.co.uk` (so losing the hyphens).  I'm hosting the site on heroku and am using their SSL cert.

My requirement is simply to have a 301 redirect on `my-site` forwarding to `mysite`.

I have udpated my config to have the site listed as the new `mysite` and I'm forcing SSL.

I had both sites listed on heroku under the custom domains, but this was throwing a horrible browser error stating the cert name could not be found.

I've now deleted the original `my-site`, but at the moment, I just get a IP not found instead of it redirecting.

The domains are on godaddy, and this is a Phoenix 1.3 app.

**update**
`non-www.my-site` does redirect but `www.my-site` does not.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Question. In your DNS configuration was the non-www pointing to Heroku via A record or alias? If the non-www no redirects correctly but the www does not it might be that the new DNS configuration has not yet propagated since CNAME nearly always take longer then A record changes.

I'm not completely sure Heroku can handle the redirects you need by only adding custom domains to the new site. It does look like your question has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15090129/5465494). An alternative solution might be redirect services like [easyredirect](https://www.easyredir.com) or if you want to roll your own this should work:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name old.tld *.old.tld;
  return 301 $scheme://www.new.tld;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name old.tld *.old.tld;
  return 301 $scheme://www.new.tld;
}
```